# Ways for client to include page ID in query?

Tags: html, http

I'm no expert on web development, and need to find a way to let the browser call a PHP routine on the server with the current document ID as parameter, eg.

http://www.acme.com/index.php?id=1

I then need to call eg. /change.php with id=1 to do something about that document.

Unless I'm mistaken, there are three ways for the client to return this information:

- if passed as argument in the URL (as above), it will be available as HTTP referrer
- by including it as hidden field in
- by sending it as cookie

I suppose using a hidden field is the most obvious choice. Are there other ways? Which solution would you recommend? Any security issues to be aware?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I needed a way for the client to learn some of the information returned by the server, such as the document ID. Apparently, the right way to solve my problem is by changing the server-side code so that this information is included in hyperlinks/forms included in the HTML page.

Comment: This belongs on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: StackExchange is like playing ping-pong ;)

Comment: @overtherainbow lol, hang on buddy, we're all still getting used to it too.

Comment: What does this sentence *I then need to call eg. /change.php with id=1 to do something about that document.* mean? Is that a link that is clicked? Or a hidden form? Or something on the backend? Question is not very clear.

Comment: You're correct on the solution. You can answer your own question if you like.  I do agree that this is a bit off-topic (it's a basic web application development question)

Comment: Keeping standard conventions you shouldn't be using ?id= on the change.php page as this is a GET request and commonly used to not change anything (immutable), use POST instead.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the deportment of the modern web is now in full motion to url-as-arguments.

http://www.acme.com/page1, http://www.acme.com/page2

http://www.acme.com/page/1, http://www.acme.com/page/2

Mod-rewrite can get you there. ([Eventually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882694/mod-rewrite-pass-the-path-query-string-url-as-a-parameter))